# Angular 4 override base url get request

Tags: angular

All GET requests in my company's Angular 4 site use a Request Options that also uses a Custom Request. A get request in the site looks like this

```
return this.http.get('Excel/download?', options)
```

This will generate **www.site1.com**/excel/download

There are around 600 GET requests and all of them will add www.site1.com at the beginning of the request and thats what I expect.

Out of all these get requests I have just one that will need to go anywhere but www.site1.com for example www.site2.com/excel/download

but when I enter in the service get request

```
return this.http.get('http://www.site2.com/Excel/download?', options)
```

the requests goes out as

http://www.**site1**.com/http://www.**site2**.com/Excel/download?

the app module has the following for all service requests and thats what provides the fixed get request.

```
{provide: RequestOptions, useClass: CustomRequestOptions}
```

Just for this ONE case how would I override this so I would just send a get request to www.site2.

**CustomRequests**

```
export class CustomRequestOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {

    merge(options?: RequestOptionsArgs): RequestOptions {
        options.url = AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT + options.url;

        if (options.method === 'put' ||
            options.method === 'post' ||
            options.method === 'patch') {
            let headers = options.headers;
            headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
            options.headers = headers;
        }

        return super.merge(options);
    }

}
```

Comment: How do your custom `CustomRequestOptions` look like? Maybe you can enhance the logic to only prepend `http://www.site1.com` if there's not already a domain in the url parameter?

Comment: I just added it to the bottom of the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may enhance RequestOptions `merge` method to only prepend the domain part if there's not already an existing one. A naiv way would be to check whether the string begins with `http://`, more sophisticated approaches could use regex to ensure it also catches `https://`.

```
merge(options?: RequestOptionsArgs): RequestOptions {
    if (options.url.indexOf('http://') !== 0) {
        options.url = AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT + options.url;
    }

    if (options.method === 'put' ||
        options.method === 'post' ||
        options.method === 'patch') {
        let headers = options.headers;
        headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
        options.headers = headers;
    }

    return super.merge(options);
}
```

You can now do `this.http.get('http://www.site2.com/Excel/download?', options)` without the `www.site1.com` part being added, but all other requests that do not have a domain at the beginning yet will still be prepended with `http://www.site1.com`

Comment: that was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you.